# Specify many option in argparse using *

Tags: python, argparse

I have a question for you! I have developed a command line tools with many options using argparse. Here is a simplified version of what I have:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--skip-part1', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('--skip-part2', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('--skip-part3', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('--skip-part4', action='store_true', default=False)
```

I would like the user to be able to select all optional *skip* arguments by typing something like

```
myscript.py --skip-*
```

Even more advanced, using regular expression:

```
myscript.py --skip-part[1-3]
```

to select the first three options only.

Do you know how I could obtain such behavior?

Thanks

Comment: no such shortcuts in argparse.

Comment: looks what you want is an additional  `--skip-part` argument, and then parse and explain value whatever you like: `--skip-part '[1-3]'`, `--skip-part '*'`, ...

Comment: There's a allow-abbrev parameter that controls whether it expects exact match on flags, or just unambiguous abbreviations.

Comment: It is doable by performing an expansion step (using `fnmatch`) to `sys.argv` before invoking the argument parser. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
parser.add_argument('--skip', action='store', default=None, nargs=1) # nargs = 1 means that 1 argument is accepted
```

When you call something like `myscript.py --skip 1-3` `args.skip == ["1-3"]` will be true.
So you get a list with one string.
With this string you can do whatever you want. You could split it at "-" to get the start and the end for Example.

Comment: I like this solution very much, it doesn't complicate much the structure of the code and gets me to the point.

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` requires statically defined option names.

However you can preprocess `sys.argv` to perform any type of expansion by yourself, and then call `parse_args()`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--skip-part1', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('--skip-part2', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('--skip-part3', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('--skip-part4', action='store_true', default=False)

# expand sys.argv:
import sys
import fnmatch
all_options = [opt
               for a in parser._actions
               for opt in a.option_strings
              ]
new_argv = []
for arg in sys.argv:
    matched = False
    for opt in all_options:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(opt, arg):
            matched = True
            new_argv.append(opt)
    if not matched:
        new_argv.append(arg)
sys.argv = new_argv

print(parser.parse_args())
```

now passing `--skip-part[1-3]` will return you
`Namespace(skip_part1=True, skip_part2=True, skip_part3=True, skip_part4=False)` and passing `--skip-*` will enable all matching switches.